# SPA client accessing ServiceStack session

Tags: angular, session, cookies, servicestack

I am developing a SPA in Angular 4 backed by ServiceStack based web services and wanted to enable the SPA to check if the user is already authenticated using the Redis cache client implemented in the backend against a custom auth provider instead of having them to login again. So, when the user is logged into another ServiceStack based application which also has the Redis cache client enabled and transfers over to this application's link (hosted as another app in the same domain), they don't have to sign in. Should I be passing any cookies or anything over to the new application as I transfer them over to the new application? Any pointers would be appreciated.

[ServiceStack Authentication Documentation](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#use-http-headers-to-send-session-cookies) describes the concept of using HTTP headers to send session cookies. Is this something I can utilize and how and where in the life cycle of the application can I capture this information to check the user is already signed in? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 2 different ServiceStack instances configured to use the same Redis Caching Provider and Custom Auth Provider then you would only need to send the same [Session Cookies](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions) in order to be treated as authenticated in both.

> (hosted as another app in the same domain)

If it's hosted in the same domain at different hosts, e.g:

```
domain.com/app1
domain.com/app2
```

Then the Session Cookies will automatically be sent when an Ajax Request is made to either App.

However if the App's are in separate sub domains, e.g:

```
app1.domain.com
app2.domain.com
```

They're treated as 2 different domains by default which won't be able to share cookies, but you can specify that cookies should apply to your root domain instead by configuring it in your `Web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies domain=".domain.com" />
</system.web>
```

Where your Ajax requests will send Cookies to both sub domains.

If you have Apps hosted in 2 different domains you wont be able to share cookies in which case you can try sending them as [Custom HTTP Headers](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#use-http-headers-to-send-session-cookies) which if your using ServiceStack's [TypeScript JsonServiceClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client) you can populate it with:

```
 var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
 client.headers.set('X-ss-id', sessionId);
```

The issue then becomes allowing Ajax clients to send custom HTTP Headers across domains which you'll need to register in your [CorsFeature](http://docs.servicestack.net/corsfeature), e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
    allowOriginWhitelist: new[] { "http://source.domain.com" },
    allowCredentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Allow, Authorization, X-ss-id"));
```

Note: the session Id is returned in the `ss-id` cookie or you can get it from the [AuthenticateResponse](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/0242748a34f88325bde05f78e898a137a92c50e0/src/ServiceStack.Client/AuthDtos.cs#L48) DTO by calling `/auth` endpoint from an authenticated user.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated!